# Cовет по шаблонизации

Tags: php, шаблонизаторы, mvc

Есть MVC система с разделением приложения по модулям. И содержит такую структуру:

```
application -> module1 -> model,view,controller
application -> module2 -> model,view,controller
application -> module3 -> model,view,controller
```

Есть web шаблон, разделенный на 4 части (шапка, левый блок, правый блок, пол).
Так вот, нужно что-бы разные контроллеры можно было запускать в разных местах (в одной из 4 частей шаблона).

Ну и собственно я не знаю, с чего начать, и как организовать.
Нативный шаблонизатор который у меня уже есть http://ideone.com/RzJueF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пожалуй, начните с написания нормального шаблонизатора, или используйте smarty/twig
нормальный шаблонизатор это как минимум:

1. свой мини-язык
2. гибкая передача параметов
3. наследование шаблонов
4. автоматическое преобразование выводимых данных для защиты от XSS и т.п
5. прекомпиляция и кэширование шаблонов

Если все-таки хотите нативный шаблонизатор, тогда используйте расширение phtml, tpl это не совсем корректно. сделайте систему виджетов, виджет по своей сути это некий класс на подобии контроллера, результатом работы которого должен быть html-шаблон, т.е по сути у вас это будет Template внутри Template, можно вызывать примерно так:

```
...
<div>
    <?=new navigation_vidget(...)?>
</div>
...
```

чтобы это работало используйте встоенный метод __toString

Answer (score 2):

Тебе ещё нужен так называемый Layout - (каркас, компоновка, план, схема) - шаблон страницы целиком. Вывод контролеров встраивается в него. Например, такой

```
 +-------------+
 |             |
 |----|--------|
 |    | где-то |
 |    | тут    |
 |    |        |
 +-------------+
 |             |
 +-------------+
```

Вот тут, к примеру, контролер выводит свои результаты в виде HTML в правом блоке "где-то тут".

А ещё есть блоки сверху, снизу и слева. Там выводятся вспомогательные фрагменты HTML, которые генерируются виджетами (widget). Это, например, небольшая форма логина или форма подписки на новости, или кнопки "поделиться", или список комментариев (который включает встроенный в него виджет - форму добавления комментария), а также навигационное меню, банер, логотип, список свежих новостей и ещё много чего.

Формально виджет - это мини-контролер, который тоже может обрабатывать ввод пользователя. Формы, нарисованные с помощью виджетов, могут адресоваться к контролерам, а могут самостоятельно обрабатывать данные из GET и POST запросов.

Layout будет включать разметку HTML и указание на подключение виджетов и контролера.

```
<html>
<head>
    <% виджет мета-тегов, вывод зависит от контролера и от виджета, например title страницы или коды для Google.WebmasterTools %>
    <% виджет CSS и Javascript, вывод зависит от контролера и от виджетов, например подключение  WYSISYG редактора или код для Google.Analytics %>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <% лого %>  <% слоган %>  <% горизонтальное меню навигации %> 
    </div>
    <div class="page">
        <% боковое меню %>  <% ТУТ ВЫВОДИТСЯ РЕЗУЛЬТАТ ОТ КОНТРОЛЕРА %> 
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <% мини-лого %>  <% копирайт %>  <% вертикальное мини-меню навигации %> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Состав виджетов может быть фиксированным для layout, но может быть несколько разных layout с разным набором виджетов, а controller или отдельный action может их переключать. Бывают layout страивают в более общий layout, чтобы на разных страницах шапка и подвал были одинаковыми, а центральная часть была на всю ширину, или в две колонки, или в три колонки.